# Is it possible to get stack traces across async/await boundaries using --harmony_async_await in Node 7?

Tags: javascript, node.js, async-await, v8, bluebird

We're experimenting with using `--harmony_async_await` in Node 7, and compared to transpiling with babel for async/await are missing the ability to have long stack traces (http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.longstacktraces.html).

Obviously, it would be great if there was an option to 'just see this' - on the chrome(ium) side they appear to support it in the inspector, though the latest work on this is after v8.5.4 (i.e. not in Node 7):

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/v8/issues/detail?id=4483

https://codereview.chromium.org/2357423002/

An alternative approach would be to get v8 to use bluebird's promise implementation - but how could I do that? Overriding `global. Promise` doesn't change how async/await behave (they still use the default promises).

Comment: Interestingly, Emanuel Jöbstl suggests that replacing the built-in promise implementation which you mention actually works! https://medium.com/front-end-weekly/stack-traces-for-promises-in-node-js-46bf5f490fe4.

Comment: Replacing the promise implementation to bluebird and enabling full stack traces incurs a high performance hit 4x-5x (https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11865#issuecomment-325035479)

Comment: But node 12 finally provides native support - https://docs.google.com/document/d/13Sy_kBIJGP0XT34V1CV3nkWya4TwYx9L3Yv45LdGB6Q/edit

Comment: @kresho thanks for letting me (and everyone else) know! Perhaps something changed since I'd messed with it, or I just made a mistake. Node/v8 have certainly come a long way since this question was asked.

Comment: the feature was announced in December 2018, about a month after your question :-). Public release was on 23/4/2019, so still quite fresh.

Comment: Question was from 2016 :)

Answer (score 1):

Since NodeJS v12 async stack traces are enabled by default.

- [relevant issue](https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/11865)
- [how async stacktraces work](https://docs.google.com/document/d/13Sy_kBIJGP0XT34V1CV3nkWya4TwYx9L3Yv45LdGB6Q/edit)